# JSON path filter for arrays

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm learning JSON paths and I'm struggling with one issue. Unfortunatelly I cannot show the original file I'm working with but I recreated the issue with this simple JSON:

```html
{
   "store":{
      "book":[
         {
            "category":"reference",
            "author":"Nigel Rees",
            "title":"Sayings of the Century",
            "price":[
               {
                  "originalEnglish": 8.95,
                  "currentEnglish":11
               },
               {
                  "originalSpanish":11,
                  "currentSpanish":13
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In the original one there's more objects and arrays but basically what I'm trying to do is filter all books with category 'reference' and with originalEnglish price below 10.

I used:

```html
$..book[?(@.price.originalEnglish < 10 && @.category == 'reference')]
```

but it doesn't work. If anyone could help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Price is an array. Use the index ‘@.price[0].orignalEnglish’

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

```
$..book[?(@.price[?(@.originalEnglish < 10)] && @.category == 'reference')]
```